# How to limit QTextEdit to accept a subset of all characters?

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I need to make QTextEdit able to accept only numbers, spaces and line breaks (enter/return). How can I do it?

Comment: Qt has QLineEdit, which has a setInputMask method to restrict the user input and a setValidator method to check it. It also have a completer to suggest input. Is it possible to use QLineEdit instead of QTextEdit in your case?

Comment: I need multiline text editor.

Answer (score 4):

The QTextEdit widget doesn't offer much help here. You'll need to externally limit what it accepts by filtering its input events and the paste data. You'll most likely need to subclass the widget.

1. Reimplement the `event` method and filter the keystrokes that come in. Pass the allowed ones down to `QTextEdit::event`. Make sure that you suitably filter both key presses and key releases, if such come in.

   This could also be done by installing an event filter on the widget.
2. Reimplement the `insertFromMimeData` and/or `canInsertFromMimeData` to either remove offending characters or disallow pasting non-numeric input.

Comment: I was thinking of using event filter to achieve same, but apparently there's no paste event in Qt, so event filter can not filter pastes. It's a pity, because if using event filters would be possible, then it'd be possible to write a general purpose event filter class, which could be used to any text input widget. Now it looks like subclassing is mandatory (multiple times if there are multiple widget classes).

Comment: @hyde Ah, so you can see the key point now: the whole idea is crazy to begin with from the user experience point of view. You must let the user's keyboard keep working as designed, and merely indicate what's wrong. This could be done, for example, by highlighting the invalid characters, changing the widget's border or background to red, or adding an error message below the widget. Such indications need to be widget-specific.

Comment: In cases where character filter would be appropriate (say, a basic phone number field), I don't think allowing invalid chars to be present would be a good UX, and signalling that a keypress was received but rejected (for example by a flash/beep/vibe, or by traditional status bar message) could be done based on simple signal emitted by a general purpose filter QObject. Anyway, beyond scope of this question, and actually SO entirely.

Comment: @hyde In fact, it would be a good thing to ask on [UX SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com) :)